# Automatic Document classification with Python: Gaming articles being sorted into Sports

Tags: python, document-classification

I have a corpus of about 500 pre-categorized articles. I've taken the most commonly-used nouns and adjectives for each category and sorted them by relevance.

Each category (world, business, tech, entertainment, science, health, sports), has a few hundred words associated with it.

I am having trouble with this article:
http://www.techhive.com/article/2052311/hands-on-with-the-2ds-an-entry-level-investment.html

It is about gaming. Words like "game, player, etc" are closely associated with Sports, based on the articles i've looked at.

This article scores the following:

```
{u'business': 51, u'entertainment': 58, u'science': 48, u'sports': 62, u'health': 35, u'world': 48, u'technology': 59}
```

As you can see, technology is up there at 59, but is overtaken by sports at 62.

I am hoping that if I increase my corpus to a few thousand articles, this problem will be solved, but I don't know if this is likely.

What are your ideas on solving this issue?

I thought about having a list of giveaway words, like "Twitter, Facebook, Technology, Nintendo, etc", that would automatically cluster the article into Technology if they are present. The only problem is finding words to do this with, and also avoiding clashes with business/world, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: what algorithm, what features do you use for classification? right now can't see any means how this question relates to python.

Answer (score 0):

The gaming category should blur with hunting, war correspondence, pen-and-paper RPGs... - Anything that has a game-version of it.

I think you are looking to differentiate fact from fiction. An idea that I derive from the one which you proposed is to grab the fiction section and the fact section of a library and reduce them to a short-list and a long-list of keywords.

ed:
It's something that I have only just discovered, but the typical 'hello world' example, which is word frequency analysis, from a map-reduce framework such as Disco should let you simply point to a set of URLs which you know are either fact or fiction. You should have two lists of tuples and then you can filter these to the keywords which most certainly speak of fact or fiction.